# Understanding of bifunctor from Category Theory for Programmers - Ch. 8

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory, type-constructor, bifunctor

I'm going mental with [Chapter 8 from *Category Theory for Programmers*](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/02/03/functoriality/).

In section 8.3, Bartosz defines this type

```hs
newtype BiComp bf fu gu a b = BiComp (bf (fu a) (gu b))
```

Here, if I'm understanding a bit of Haskell, `bf`, `fu`, and `gu` are type constructors, `bf` of kind `(* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> * -> * -> *`, and `fu` and `gu` of kind `* -> *` (just like `Maybe` or `[]`), whereas `a`, and `b` are general types of kind `*`; `BiComp` ***on the left of `=`*** is a type constructor of kind to long to write, whereas `BiComp` ***on the right is a value constructor***, so it's of type `(bf (fu a) (gu b)) -> BiComp bf fu gu a b`.

Then the author makes `BiComp` a bifunctor in `a` and `b`, provided that the type constructor parameter `bf` is a `Bifunctor` too, and that the type constructors `fu` and `gu` are `Functor`s:

```hs
instance (Bifunctor bf, Functor fu, Functor gu) => Bifunctor (BiComp bf fu gu) where
    bimap f1 f2 (BiComp x) = BiComp ((bimap (fmap f1) (fmap f2)) x)
```

So far so good, all seems reasonable to me at this point. Except that using the same name for the type constructor and value constructor is probably getting me lost.

Now I'm tempted to make the following observations:

- the `bimap` on the right of the definition is the one leveraging the constraints: it's the `bimap` that is assumed as defined in the `Bifunctor` instance of whatever type contructor `bf` really is, therefore this `bimap` has type `(a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> bf a b -> bf a' b'`; I think this is less interesting than the following, because it's after all just the signature of `bimap` for the `Bifunctor` type`class` presented in 8.1;
- the `bimap` on the left, instead, is the one we are defining to make `BiComp` a `Bifunctor` in its 4th and 5th parameters; and the arguments `f1` and `f2` are function that have to act on entities of type which are those 4th and 5th parameters of `BiComp`; therefore, this `bimap`'s type is `(a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> BiComp bf fu gu a b -> BiComp bf fu gu a' b'`.

Is this correct?

If so, then I don't understand the following

```hs
bimap :: (fu a -> fu a') -> (gu b -> gu b') -> bf (fu a) (gu b) -> bf (fu a') (gu b')
```

because this is the type of the `bimap` on the right, the one I wrote in the bullet point above, except that it's written with `a` = `fu a`, `a'` = `fu a'`, and so on.

Am I missing something (or overthinking...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close.

First, you have the kind of `bf` wrong.  It's actually just `* -> * -> *`, which is exactly as expected given that it's going to be a `Bifunctor`.  Of course, the kind of `BiComp` is pretty crazy:

```hs
BiComp :: (* -> * -> *) -> (* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> * -> * -> *
```

As for the types in your bullet points, technically, they're both correct, but it might help to use fresh type variables (especially for the type in your first bullet point!) to make this all a little clearer.  In fact, the `bimap` on the right hand side has the type

```hs
bimap :: forall c c' d d'. (c -> c') -> (d -> d') -> bf c d -> bf c' d'
```

We need to use this to make something that converts our input value, of type `bf (fu a) (gu b)` to an output value of type `bf (fu a') (gu b')`.  We can do this only if we let `c ~ fu a, c' ~ fu a', d ~ gu b, d' ~ gu b'`.  Let's take a look at what that does to our RHS `bimap`:

```hs
bimap :: (fu a -> fu a') -> (gu b -> gu b') -> bf (fu a) (gu b) -> bf (fu a') (gu b')
```

Aha!  That's exactly what you found on the right hand side!  And, we can provide exactly the arguments we need.  First, a function of type `fu a -> fu a'`.  Well, we have a given function `f1 :: a -> a'` and we know that `fu` is a functor, so we can get the function we need with `fmap f1`.  Likewise with `f2` and `fmap f2`, and everything works out nicely.

Comment: Oh, now I understand my mustache: the kind I've written is that of the partially applied type constructor, `BiComp bf`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrote `forall c c' d d'.` I still have to study that part of the syntax (I've seen a lot of questions here on SO), but isn't it superflous in this case? If not, why?

Comment: So your point is that the author is indeed writing the type of the rhs `bimap`, not the the lhs?

Comment: You don't actually need the `forall` part; if you omit it, it's implied.  That said, I find it makes it very clear which type variables are _new_, and which are inherited.  For instance, in that signature, `bf` is not part of the `forall`, meaning that it is actually fixed, while the `forall` type variables can be instantiated with anything you want when you call the function.  Yes, the `bimap :: (fu a -> fu a') -> ...` type is the rhs, not the lhs.